# Accessing Microsoft visual source safe over the internet

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

I am working on a software project which uses the Microsoft Visual source safe version control system. I need to access this system from home as I often work on source code files from there. How I can VSS be setup so that it can be accessed from the internet as well.

Answer (score 2):

Visual SourceSafe 2005 includes support for access over HTTP:

> **Remote Internet Access.** This release of Visual SourceSafe
>   introduces a new SourceSafe Internet
>   plug-in for Visual Studio source
>   control. The plug-in and its
>   associated Web service enable remote
>   Internet access to Visual SourceSafe
>   databases over HTTP or HTTPS. The
>   SourceSafe Internet plug-in supports
>   the basic operations of database open,
>   database add, check-in, checkout, and
>   get, but does not provide rename,
>   delete, get by time or by label,
>   history, labeling, or share/branch
>   functions. This plug-in is
>   particularly helpful when you need to
>   access your Visual SourceSafe
>   databases when you are on the road.

Articles on setting it up seem to be scarce: [Visual SourceSafe 2005 Internet Provider](http://www.yafla.com/dennisforbes/Visual-SourceSafe-2005-Internet-Provider/Visual-SourceSafe-2005-Internet-Provider.html).

Also see:

- [How to: Enable Internet Information Services (IIS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181052(VS.80).aspx)
- [How to: Set Up Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181053(VS.80).aspx)

But given that Visual SourceSafe 2005 will be retired from mainstream support on 12 April 2011 (with extended support ending on 12 April 2016), you might be better off going with Subversion (or similiar).